# No values given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I am getting error as "No values given for one or more required parameters" Please help. For Nid.Text value is "N712".

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection cont1 = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\vsual\Database3.accdb");
            OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("select distinct UserName from Users where UID=@UID ", cont1);
            OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("select distinct QueueName from Users where UID=@UID ", cont1);
            OleDbCommand cmd3 = new OleDbCommand("select * from Issues", cont1);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", Nid.Text);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", Nid.Text);
            cont1.Open();
            OleDbDataReader rdr1= cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            while(rdr1.Read())
            {
                txtName.Text = rdr1[0].ToString();
            }
            OleDbDataReader rdr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr2.Read())
            {
                txtQueue.Text= rdr2[0].ToString();
            }
            txtName.Enabled = false;
            txtQueue.Enabled = false;

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd3;
            da.Fill(ds);
            cmbIssue.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            cmbIssue.ValueMember = "Issues";
            cmbIssue.DisplayMember = "Issues";
            cmbIssue.Enabled = true;

        }
```

All i got from internet is some issue with sql statement. Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try moving `cont1.Open();` right before using `OleDbCommand`.

Comment: Can you try like this: `"select distinct UserName from Users where UID=?"`

Answer (score 0):

I tried testing your code and got the same error, but then fixed up my database to match your query and it worked fine.

Upon deleting a column from the table to test, the error reappeared. So I think in this case it is just a misleading error message, and actually your database is missing a column you reference in your query (as opposed to a problem with your parameter).

e.g. deleting the QueueName column from Users broke `cmd2` with the message you stated.

Have a look at your database and make sure the columns match your query. i.e. your `UserName` table should have columns `UID`, `UserName`, `QueueName` and your `Issues` table should have a `Issues` column.

**Update:** Adding images of the data I used to successfully run your code. Please have a look and see if anything doesn't match your data. Particularly check data types.

Users schema:

[image: Users schema]

Users data:

[image: Users data]

Issues schema:

[image: Issues schema]

Issues data:

[image: Issues data]

Comment: Database is correct. `Users` table has columns `UID`, `UserName`, `QueueName` and `Issues` table has column `Issues`.

Answer (score 0):

This might help but not sure.

The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?
```

Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

Source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: It was my bad. The address of Database was pointing to old database. So my changed database was not getting fetched. Now everything works fine. Thanks all for your help.